# Auto-renewable subscription, determine initial purchase

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

In the updatedtransactions method when the transactionState reflects the purchased state, I'd like to determine whether it's a new purchase or a renewal. Is this possible from the data? I couldn't find anything. I did see the originalTransaction but it says this is only defined for a restore, not a purchase. I could of course keep a flag in the app, but unfortunately I don't get information about when a subscription is cancelled. I could keep checking after each period whether it's renewed but there might be a slight gap there and this will get messy.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to display this message on every Renewal of Subscription or only on the very first time subscription?

Comment: every first purchase of a subscription. so i buy X.. message ... renew X... no message... dont renew X... repurchase X... message... etc

Answer (score 0):

Verify the receipt as in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html. You get the original_purcahse_date_ms. Compare it to the purchase_date_ms... voila!

Comment: I thought this was the answer. But now I'm wondering. It says: original_purchase_date:
This holds the purchase date for the initial purchase; it represents the start date for the subscription. What if you end your subscription, repurchase the product? I've found that it returns the date of first ever purchase of the product. Not the first purchase of that particular subscription period. I'm wondering if these are just the usual iTunes test user issues of overusing an account... or?

Answer (score 0):

After your transactionState becomes purchasedState, you will want to verify the receipt as laid out in "[Verifying an Auto-Renewable Subscription Receipt](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH4-SW5)".

You'll query the store and get a JSON response, which includes a receipt field - in this receipt is original_purchase_date. From what I understand, this is not the same as the transactionDate of the originalTransaction you found in your SKPaymentTransaction. The documentation says:

> This holds the purchase date for the initial purchase; it represents the start date for the subscription.

If that query is also returning the very first subscription date, another approach would be to store this information on your own server, and validate the receipts there (mentioned at the very end of the section linked above).

Comment: I am already doing this. But the original_purchase_date_ms turns out to be the very first time you purchased the subscription. If you end the subscription and restart it ... the original_purchase_date remains unchanged unfortunately (at least in the sandbox). Also, my client does not want own server (< time = < $$)

Comment: You may want to check that the type of content you're offering is allowed to be sold as a auto-renewable subscription. See https://developer.apple.com/news/pdf/in_app_purchase.pdf for the full scoop. One example of "not allowed" content is "Auto-Renewing subscription to monthly voice-guidance service" because it is non-episodic in nature. It seems like you have to be providing new content every renewal period for this to be used. Without a server side, I'm not sure if this is going to be allowed. Non-auto-renewable might be for you.

Comment: Yeah, the app I am building is allowed to use auto-renewable subscriptions. It has already gone through the review process with auto-renewable subscriptions with success. The app was written by someone else and I decided to take a 3rd party library out that took care of the In-App purchases. That's why I'm rewriting it. I don't know how this has anything to do with having a server side though...